# Which permission for pictures? 644?

Tags: permission, graphics

In order to avoid some non wanted modifications or corruption of pictures files, one possibility is to change the permissions of the files (in `~/Pictures`).

Do you think that this idea is a good one? And which permissions? `644` on files and `755` on directories?

Comment: all the files are all in your home directory, only you can  access them except you share them via network sharing e.g. so don't worry about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0644` is good for pictures. `0755` is only needed for executable files and directories (thanks, Mateusz).

Note that `0644` grants read access to all users. If you want to deny read access to other users, then you might consider `0600` instead.

More info: [`man 1 chmod`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html).

Comment: `0755` is also needed for directories.